# Helo on debugger in xcode, using swift and swiftUI 5

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, swiftui

**HI**

so after some research about debugger, i still have no idea how this works :

```
    2021-08-29 05:04:47.699766+0200 TestbaseThemed[7017:392999] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032c2b70 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f9861d13590]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f9861d10e60'Theme'd']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032c2bc0 'CB_Trailing_Trailing' _UIModernBarButton:0x7f9861d10e60'Theme'd'.trailing <= _UIButtonBarButton:0x7f9861d10770.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032c39d0 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x7f9861d13590.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x6000028e0b60'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032c3a20 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7f9861d10770]-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000028e0a80'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032c8eb0 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x6000028e0a80'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x7f9863811270.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032c40a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x7f9863811270.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032c9270 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000028e0b60'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x7f9863811270 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000032c2b70 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f9861d13590]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7f9861d10e60'Theme'd']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

i'm currently trying to debug and it kinda f**ked up my program. Before it caused no problem, because i wasn't loading things before the lunch of the program
but now, it get me in trouble because as soon as the error shows up, the func stop functionning and it doesn't load the rest of what it should load

i also though about waiting the func to be done before doing anything else, but idk how to do it
so i guess i'll have to deal with debugging

thanks in advance for the answers !

(So, luckily i found the error, but i have no clue why it does that :
.navigationTitle("Theme'd")
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
)
i was lucky

Comment: If you see some `NSLayoutConstraint` violated that you did not create, for example when using the SwiftUI, you can ignore it: this is not your fault.

Comment: Oh
well look like it's not my fault

Answer (score 0):

In general, one of the constraint is not flexible enough to help resize based on screen size.

For example, if you have a view which is supposed to be of width 200 and have left and right margins as 0. Here all 3 cannot be simultaneously fulfilled unless device width is 200.

A solution to the above example I mentioned would be one of the following -

1. **Remove one of the constraint**.
2. **Make one of the constraints as greater / less than**.
3. **Reduce priority of one of constraint**.

The result would be either the view will then move to left or right and have 200 width or it will be with margins 0 and flexible width.

Comment: so i guess `UINavigationBarContentView` = .navigationTitle("Theme'd")
how can i delete the width constraint ?